# Escape single quote in redshift sql in a column value

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

[image]

As per the attached image the column tlist in a table 'c' has values separated by a comma such as 'HCC19','HCC18'.
I am trying to used the column values in a query condition on redshift ..

`where a.risk_factor in (c.tlist)`
.. ..but its not giving the expected result possibly because its taking the value a single string as   '
`where a.risk_factor in( ' 'HCC19','HCC18' ')` and not as required in the expression `where a.risk_factor  in('HCC19','HCC18')`

Is there any workaround possible for this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using a `LIKE` comparison here:

```
WHERE c.tlist LIKE '%''' || a.risk_factor || '''%';
```

The above `LIKE` expression compares `'HCC19','HCC18'` searching for the single quoted risk factor.  If the risk factor already comes with single quotes, then just use:

```
WHERE c.tlist LIKE '%' || a.risk_factor || '%';
```